# Is SE/SO still using OData for data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

This is more of a discussion than a question.

Is SE/SO network still using [OData](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Data_Protocol) for the website https://data.stackexchange.com/?

To me looks like yes, but isn't OData dead? As Microsoft is not moving forward with [WCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) data services anymore and more like trying to encourage people to use web API.

Do we keep using it?

Comment: Why would the Microsoft stance on OData have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Oded Microsoft is one of major contributor to tech we use to develop products like web services & so, which is why I believe they will have some impact

Comment: Still, OData is not driven solely by Microsoft. The technology lives on its own and has wide support outside of the MS world.

Comment: What do you mean by "web API"? [ASP.NET Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#Extension)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 1):

The OData endpoints were disabled due to various problems as stated by [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190017/odata-access-from-data-stackexchange-com-down/192382#192382)

> However, if it breaks again due to another move or such we likely will not fix it.

and due to that fact I submitted a PR in 2015 to remove the last remains of that OData history:

[Hide the broken OData link in Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247931/hide-the-broken-odata-link-in-data-explorer)